# Add items into dropdown using ajax/jquery using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

This may be the duplicate question but I would like to mention that other answers have not solved my problem.

As the question says, I want to populate the dropdown using ajax/jquery. I am able to send and recieve data in the JSON format successfully but it does not append with the dropdown. Following is my code:

**View**

```
  <select name="guard_id" id="guard_id" style="width:100%;">
    <option>select guard</option>
       <optgroup label="Previously assigned guard" id="trained_guards">
       </optgroup>
  </select>
```

**Jquery/Ajax call**

```
function checkTrainedGuards(sid) {

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php print site_url('roster/check_trained_guards'); ?>',
            data: { sid: sid},
            beforeSend:function() {
                // this is where we append a loading image
                $('#sid').addClass('loader-roster');
            },
            success:function(data) {
             var appenddata;
             $.each(data, function (key, value) {

             appenddata += "<option value = '" + value.gid + " '>" + value.gname + " </option>";                        
             });
            $('#trained_guards').html(appenddata);

            },
            error:function(){
                // failed request; give feedback to user
            }
        });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
  public function check_trained_guards(){

        $this->load->model("guard");
        $sid=$this->input->post("sid");

        $trainedGuards=$this->guard->getGuardAlreadyWorkedOnSite($sid);

        foreach ($trainedGuards as $guard) {

        print json_encode(array(
            'gid'  => $guard->gid,
            'gname' => $guard->guard_name
        ));
        }
      }
}
```

When I test it using firebug, I an see the data is coming correct and it is in JSON format as shown below:

```
[{"gid":"293","gname":"Abc"},{"gid":"96","gname":"guard2"},{"gid":"101","gname":"guard3"},{"gid":"91","gname":"guard4"}]
```

However, I am just wondering why it is not appending the result into dropdown box?

I, Also tested this by `alert(value.gid)` in the `jquery each loop` it says `undefined`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: for starters, set `var appenddata = "";` in your success callback.  then try console.logging it before using the html method to see what its equal to.

Comment: I does not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON seems to be in wrong format . Your php part should look like follows :

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($trainedGuards as $guard) {
$arr[] = $guard;

}

print json_encode($arr);
```

Now this code will return a valid JSON as Follows. JOSN will the array of objects shown below :

```
[{"gid":"2","gname":"Gurd1"},{"gid":"3","gname":"Guard2"}]
```

In your ajax response write following code

```
 var data = [{"gid":"2","guard_name":"Gurd1"},{"gid":"3","guard_name":"Guard2"}]; 
//This is the response format  You can also use JSON.parse if its in the string format



    var appenddata = "";
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {

    appenddata += "<option value = '" + value.gid + " '>" + value.gname + " </option>";                        
    });
$('#trained_guards').html(appenddata);
```